# Would my wall be load bearing?

Tags: walls, load-bearing

I have a room which is 210 inches x 144 inches.
There is a wall 4 feet from the left hand wall which is the one that is 144 inches. So 48 inches into the 210 inch wall. Which used to be a very tiny bathroom.

I was wondering if that all would be load bearing based on the image of the roof that is above it shown in the given image.

Thanks[image: Roof configuration]

Comment: Really the only thing we can tell with that picture is that you might want more insulation.

Comment: This is strange.  Do you have joists under the insulation that parallel the rafters?

Comment: The house makes an L shape and this is the small part of the L. And the beams run parrallel to the roof (same direction as seen in the picture). These beams go from wall to wall Also we are in the process of adding insulation in the roof, but comment is very much appreciated!